# How to compute CDF for Lognormal distribution survival formula

Tags: survival

I would like to manually compute the lognormal distribution but I am not clear on how to compute the CDF value that is required in the formula for the Survival function.

The formula is as below:

$S(x)=1−Φ(\frac{ln(x)}{σ})$

Is there a way to get this value using R?

Thanks

Comment: so far what I have done is to use this formula in R: S(t) = 1 - plnorm(log(t) / model$scale) . Is this correct?

Comment: Why doesn't $\mu$ appear in your formula?

Comment: okay i found this link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33664/mean-survival-time-for-a-log-normal-survival-function?rq=1 with another formula. Does this mean that the μ comes from the survreg function?

Comment: it shows from this link: http://blogs2.datall-analyse.nl/2016/02/17/rcode_3_parameter_lognormal_correct_likelihood/ that the mu is taken from coef of the survreg function. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't able to post this yesterday -- I eventually figured out that the point of the non-mu formula is just as a "standard" form of lognormal with median 1, which you might treat as a multiplicative error term. In that case, yes, the mean survival (conditional on the predictors) would supply the mu that this would represent the variation around.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for the formula when coding it in R and it is as below

$S(t) = 1 - plnorm(t, meanlog, sdlog)$

both the meanlog and sdlog value can be derived from computing the shape and the scale from the survreg results.